# Apache Commons Daemon specify classpath

Tags: java, apache-commons, procrun, apache-commons-daemon, prunsrv

I try to deploy a program as windows service with apache commons daemon. i have everything set up fine beside the classpath.

```
Classpath=C:\test\test-service\lib\*
```

specifies where the service itself lies, but the service needs some configuration files to run and these are under

```
Classpath=C:\test\test-service\conf\*
```

now i struggle to get it to work so that the program uses `C:\test\test-service\*` as classpath and not just one of the both specified above. sadly `C:\test\test-service\*` does not work and throws a `ClassDefNotFoundException` for the starter class. that error is solved by `C:\test\test-service\lib\*` but then i get the error that my config files can't be read. therefore i thought, why not also add the config path to the classpath like this:

```
Classpath=C:\test\test-service\lib\*;C:\test\test-service\conf\*
```

but this still throws the `FileNotFoundException`. does anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by myself. Following works:

```
Classpath= C:\test\test-service\conf\;C:\test\test-service\lib\*
```

it takes all files in conf folder by default as well as all files from lib as the `*` states